# How do I make the ssh connection from my country only?

Tags: bash, ssh

I tried to do this:
apt install geoip-bin geoip-database

I created this script in:
/usr/local/bin/

nano filter.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
ALLOW_COUNTRIES="SA"
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
  echo "Usage:  `basename $0` <ip>" 1>&2
  exit 0
fi

COUNTRY=`/usr/share/GeoIP $1 | awk -F ": " '{ print $2 }' | awk -F "," '{ print $1 }' | head -n 1`

[[ $COUNTRY = "IP Address not found" || $ALLOW_COUNTRIES =~ $COUNTRY ]] && RESPONSE="ALLOW" || RESPONSE="DENY"
if [ $RESPONSE = "ALLOW" ]
then
  exit 0
else
  logger "$RESPONSE sshd connection from $1 ($COUNTRY)"
  exit 1
fi
```

`chmod +X filter.sh`

to enable it, In `/etc/hosts.deny` I added:

```
sshd: ALL
```

in `/etc/hosts.allow` I added:

```
sshd: ALL: aclexec /usr/local/bin/filter.sh %a
```

but the problem is when I type `bash filter.sh anyIP`, I get `/usr/share/GeoIP is a directory` error.

Comment: There are several packages and utilities called GeoIP. Which one are you using, and is `/usr/share/GeoIP` an executable?

Comment: What's not clear in `/usr/share/GeoIP is a directory`? How would you use geoip manually? Add a link to the instructions you followed. Copy&paste the output of `dpkg -L geoip-bin`.

Comment: this is the package:
apt install geoip-bin geoip-database.
no, /usr/share/GeoIP, but How I can use the database provided?

Comment: @Bodo:
https://www.axllent.org/docs/ssh-geoip/

Comment: @ibraheemmohsen Please [edit] your question to add requested information, don't use comments for this purpose. The linked instructions tell you to run a command `geoiplookup`, and the output of `dpkg -L geoip-bin` would show you that this command is in `/usr/bin/geoiplookup`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to these descriptions ([geoip-bin](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/amd64/geoip-bin/filelist), [geoip-database](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/all/geoip-database/filelist)), `/usr/share/GeoIP` is indeed a directory, being a part of geoip-database package, that contains two database files, `GeoIP.dat` and `GeoIPv6.dat`.

You cannot use a directory name as a command. You also cannot use a database file as a command. You have to use a name of an actual executable command that can be run. This will be probably `/usr/bin/geoiplookup` from the package geoip-bin (see description in the first link).

So replace `/usr/share/GeoIP` in your script with `/usr/bin/geoiplookup` and it should work.